# How do I tell Googlebot and Bingbot that there will be more links below the current viewport

Tags: seo, google, links, bing

So I have a blog post which is rendered on the server, so this should not be a problem. Now below the post there is a standard "Recommended Section" with related posts, but I fetch these posts only if they appear in the viewport of the browser so that I don't need the user to download extra data and I don't need to add extra reads for my database.

But will a crawler have problems with that occurring, and if so, what can I do to let it find these links?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by `viewport is on a certain level` (dimensions, and if so which)? Also, are you referring to Googlebot, or all crawlers, because they differ greatly. Googlebot uses a headless version of Chrome, which you can view the results of by using Fetch as Google.

Comment: @dan Ah okay, I talk about the important search engines so basicly Google and maybe Bing too. Ok didnt know about such a tool.

Comment: @dan Yes when the viewport is on a certain level but not hard coded, just when the Content is in the viewport, because a article can have a height of 100px or 2000px so it would be bad to hardcode the dimensions

Comment: I suspect you mean it's _responsive_ to the device viewing it? Can you edit the question to clarify that and be more specific to Google and Bing then, since it's really too broad as it is. Bing also has a similar tool:  [Fetch as Bingbot](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/fetch-as-bingbot-fe18fa0d).

Comment: @dan I think my question in terms of viewport is precise. If the Recommended Section gets into viewport then it gets fetched, otherwise it doesnt, device or a fixed height doesnt matter there.

Comment: I think you mean the content with the links is only displayed if it's in the current viewport - does that mean if the user scrolls, or just to where the page loads with scrolling? Users need to know what those dimensions would be since the Googlebot will cutoff pages past a certain height and width.

Comment: I edited the question based on your comments, and to make it specific to just Google and Bing, since _all search crawlers_ is really too broad.You can edit it further if I misunderstood something. You can view your pages with the _Fetch as_ tools - if the "Recommended Section" doesn't appear in their results, you'll need to add some JavaScript to trigger it for smaller dimensions.